# My app crashes onitemclick in listview inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my fragment and onitemclicklistener. When I run the app it shows me a list but when I click on such the app crashes. Can someone see what could be the reason for such to be hapenning?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) result.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MovieDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MOVIE_DETAILS", (MovieDetails) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

> Process: com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch, PID: 10943 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch/com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch.MovieDetailActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: can you paste your `logcat` Error.

Comment: Process: com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch, PID: 10943
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch/com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch.MovieDetailActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I see now there is a problem with the AndroidManifest, can you tell me what exactly to add in the android manifest file ? thank you so much

Comment: please declare this activity in `Manifest` file **`MovieDetailActivity`**

Comment: add it within the `application` tag.  You will see other activities there as well.  Its better to make new activities by file->new->new activity. Its is added automatically.

Comment: thank you so much for your help :)))))

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your Android Manifest inside application tag:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.vjezba.androidtab.tabswitch.MovieDetailActivity" />
```